# numpy `astype(int)` gives `np.int64` instead of `int` - what to do?

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion

I've got a standard `np.array` with type `np.int32`:

`idx = array([ 607,  638,  639, ..., 9279, 9317, 9318], dtype=int32)`

To make sure `int32` is actually `np.int32`, I check with:

```
>>> type(idx[0])
<class 'numpy.int32'>
```

To use this array later on, I need these to be of type `int` (the reason is that I want do index a `std::vector<T>` using `cppyy` which seems to be strict on the index type). Hence I though I could do

`>>> idx2 = idx.astype(int)`

but this gives

```
>>> type(idx2[0])
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Do I have to use something like this?

```
>>> idx3 = [int(k) for k in idx]
>>> type(idx3[0])
<class 'int'>
```

Any advice?

*Update 1*: Perhaps this will provide some more information on the indexing of a `std::vector`:

```
>>> v[idx[0]]
*** TypeError: an integer is required
```

whereas

```
>>> v[int(idx[0])]
<cppyy.gbl.std.vector<double> object at 0x559a9a8845a8>
```

*Update 2*: For me, converting to list is satisfactory, and I've accepted this answer.

Comment: A C++ *int* (fixed size) is different from a Python *int* (unbounded). Are you sure you need a Python `int`?

Comment: An array can have dtypes like `int64` or `int32` (and various aliases).  `int`, as in base python `int` is not a possible dtype.  While a list contains references to python objects, `ind2[0]` is not such a reference.  Instead it is a `np` object, such as `np.int64` whose value is taken from the array.  So `type(ind2[0])` is not a useful test.  Example code of you will use the array wth `cppyy` should help.

Comment: Python's int can be arbitarily large and therefore is some sort of Big Int implementation (see pts's comment above). Therefore it isn't really what you need for indexing purpose.

Comment: That `index a std::vector<T> using cppyy` needs to be clearer.  I'd suggest closing this question, and posting a new one that focuses on that c++ link. Python/numpy types aren't helpful.  Maybe even post some code and errors..

Comment: Thank you hpaulj for the valuable points on np arrays not being able to hold `int` as well as pointing out that I should be clearer regarding the indexing of `std::vector` using cppyy. I've updated my question, but also accepted the answer suggesting converting to a list, which is perfectly fine in my current situation.

Comment: `tolist` is a good fast way of getting 'native' python values from an array.  If for example if you have to iterate, `for i in arr.tolist():` saves time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`.tolist()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html):

```py
idx = np.array([607, 638, 939], dtype=np.int32)
idx3 = idx.tolist()

print(type(idx3[0]))
```

Prints:

```
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: While that produces a list of python `int` objects, how will that be useful when iterfacing to C++ code?

Comment: The goal of the OP is not to obtain a list of python's int object but rather than indexing ```std::vector<T>```

Comment: @MCiel which means that Python's `int` type is worthless here, the OP is misguided.  The C++ `int` type will almost certainly match one of numpy's `int32` or `int64` types.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes. It is implied that OP wants to know how to obtain a list of python's ```int``` type (and therefore this answer) but that is irrelevant to their actual objective (XY problem??).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep numpy array, you can convert int32/int64 to `object`:

```
test_array = np.arange(10).astype(object)
print(type(test_array[0]))
```

```
<class 'int'>
```

EDIT: Funny thing, you cant use it as indices. This produces error:

```
test_array[test_array]
```

```
{IndexError}arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

Comment: A list of python int used as index will be converted to an array with `int32/64` dtype and work.  But if it's already an array it won't use astype to convert it back. But none of this relevant when somehow using the array with c++ 'vectors'.